# JSON access field as different Schemas

Tags: c#, json

I have the following JSON definitions:

```
    public class Msg
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "commandId")]
        public int CommandId { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "params")]
        public JnoParams Parameters = new JnoParams();
    }


    public class Res_Msg
    {        
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "commandId")]
        public int CommandId { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "params")]
        public Dev_Result Parameters = new Dev_Result();
    }
```

The property "params" has different JSON definitions, in the first one it is an empty structure, in the second it contains fields with values returned by the device.
When the WebSocket returns a packet to the app, I determine what to do based on the two fields "commandId" and "id" and am trying to unwrap the "params" with a different structure definition depending on the values in commandId and id.
If I had to use plain old 'c' language I would use a union, but I'm using JSON definitions.
How can I tell C# that "params" is of one type rather than another and therefore access its fields accordingly?
I thought I could convert from  type1 to  type2 or somehow cast it, but so far have been unsuccessful.
Thank you much for any hint.

Answer (score 0):

Well;
apparently I didn't have to define every possible JSON structure in order to retrieve the values from them.
I defined the JSON for those structures I was going to use and within these structures, I only defined the fields I am interested in.
After decades spent describing structures that had to be defined exactly as the various fields in terms of type and size, it is a refreshing feeling to see that all I need really is to define the type of JSON packet and the name and type of field contained in it that I want to extract, in order for JSON to find it and return it, without any need to define in the JSON structure all the fields before it or after.